# Magento 2 DropDown Attribute - Get "Admin" label value, not the StoreView value

Tags: magento2, attributes

how can i get the "Admin" label value, not the StoreView value

[image]

with

```
    $_product = $this->getProduct();
    $state = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('m4y_state')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

    return $state;
```

i get the StoreView value, but i need the Admin Value (red).

[image]

How can i do that?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Solve my Problem with ->setStoreId(0)

Comment: $_product = $this->getProduct();
$state = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('m4y_state')->setStoreId(0)->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been trying to do the same thing.